# xhr posting data on Firefox and page redirection: NS_BINDING_ABORTED

Tags: javascript, firefox, xmlhttprequest, jspsych

I am trying to code a jsPsych experiment, hosted on a LAMP server. Everything works well; at the end, I am trying to move to the next task by performing a redirection.

Here is the code:

```
saveData(save_url, data_dir, file_name, extension, redirect_html, redirectToNextPage);

function saveData(save_url, data_dir, file_name, extension, redirect_html, callback) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', save_url); // 'write_data.php' is the path to the php file used to save the data
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
                // Data was saved successfully, now trigger the callback function
                callback(redirect_html);
            } else {
                // Handle any errors that occurred during data saving
                console.error('Error saving data: ' + xhr.status);
            }
        }
    };
    xhr.send(JSON.stringify({file_name: file_name, extension: extension, data_dir: data_dir, data: jsPsych.data.get().csv()}));
}

function redirectToNextPage(redirect_html) {

    if((window.location.href).indexOf('?') != -1) {
        var variables = window.location.href.split('?')[1]; 
        redirect_html += "?" + variables;
    };

    last_trial_data = jsPsych.data.getLastTrialData().trials[0];
    if(last_trial_data["chain"] != "false"){
        window.location = redirect_html;
    };  

}
```

Despite waiting for a confirmation that the data is posted using `xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE` and `xhr.status === 200` before calling the function to perform the redirection, running the experiment on Firefox induces a `NS_BINDING_ABORTED` error. I understand that what is happening is that the request gets cancelled by the redirection (as running the experiment without the redirection works properly and the data is sent).

Would anyone have an idea of what is going wrong?

Comment: Does only `Firefox` returns this exception or does the same thing happen with other browsers too?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer. This issue only appears on Firefox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We ended up finding a solution that seems to work by calling a Promise, I will leave the code below for posterity:

```
function saveData(save_url, data_dir, file_name, extension) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('POST', save_url);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
                if (xhr.status === 200) {
                    resolve();
                } else {
                    reject(new Error('Error saving data: ' + xhr.status));
                }
            }
        };
    xhr.send(JSON.stringify({file_name: file_name, extension: extension, data_dir: data_dir, data: jsPsych.data.get().csv()}));
    });
}

// Usage of async/await for the redirection
async function saveAndRedirect(save_url, data_dir, file_name, extension, redirect_html) {
    try {
        await saveData(save_url, data_dir, file_name, extension);
        redirectToNextPage(redirect_html);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}

function redirectToNextPage(redirect_html) {

    if((window.location.href).indexOf('?') != -1) {
        var variables = window.location.href.split('?')[1]; 
        redirect_html += "?" + variables;
    };

    last_trial_data = jsPsych.data.getLastTrialData().trials[0];
    if(last_trial_data["chain"] != "false"){
        window.location = redirect_html;
    };  

}
```

Comment: Perfect. Please mark this answer as "correct". In case you get more answers everyone can see that you've already found a solution.